# Function overloading with generics: "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target."

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a signature that is compatible to both calls below. The first one seems to work fine, but the second one says `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`. Any ideas?

```
interface I1 {
    name: string;
}

interface I2 {
    age: number;
}

function set<T, KT extends keyof T>(arg1: KT, arg2?: undefined): (value: T[KT]) => void;
function set<T, KT extends keyof T, U, KU extends keyof U>(arg1: KT, arg2: KU): (value: U[KU]) => void {
    // ...
    return null;
}

set<I1, "name">("name"); // OK
set<I1, "name", I2, "age">("name", "age"); // ERROR: "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the last function is not counted in the overload candidates. It's the implementation that's supposed to handle all of them.

The following works:

```
interface I1 {
    name: string;
}

interface I2 {
    age: number;
}

function set<T, KT extends keyof T>(arg1: KT, arg2?: undefined): (value: T[KT]) => void;
function set<T, KT extends keyof T, U, KU extends keyof U>(arg1: KT, arg2: KU): (value: U[KU]) => null;
function set<T, KT extends keyof T, U, KU extends keyof U>(arg1: KT, arg2: KU): (value: U[KU]) => null {
    // ...
    return null;
}

const x = set<I1, "name">("name"); // OK
const y = set<I1, "name", I2, "age">("name", "age"); // Now OK
```

Comment: Second time you've made my day! You truly are The most powerful shinobi of the time.